# No View Found for ID (dynamic feature module)

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

I have a dynamic feature module with an activity that I'm trying to launch. However, I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x81020009 (com.example.dynamicFeatureModule/fragment_container) for fragment MyFragment{49b6ef} (ae09d134-2898-4fd5-9d39-33f371b57e74 id=0x81020009)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
        at
```

The weird thing is, I am able to access a string using `R.string.` so not sure why the `layout` and the `id` are behaving differently.

```
class MyActivity : FragmentActivity() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
        // Emulates installation of on demand modules using SplitCompat.
        SplitCompat.installActivity(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)

        val str = getString(R.string.my_string) // this is fine

        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(
                R.id.fragment_container,
                MyFragment::class.java,
            )
            .commit()
    }
}
```

This is my `my_activity.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

In my base application class, I have:

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        // Emulates installation of future on demand modules using SplitCompat.
        SplitCompat.install(this);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Update: Filed a bug with Google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230101698

Comment: I was able to get this working by placing my layout in another module, and importing it like `com.example.othermodule.R.layout.my_activity` and `com.example.othermodule.R.id.fragment_container` but not sure why I have to do that

Comment: This could be a bug with the AndroidX Fragment library. Updating to 1.4.1 might fix this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71986621/4138919